# Speed up MERGE in SQL Server on millions of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, merge, sqlperformance

I'm trying to insert/update millions of rows into a table that already contains millions of rows.

The target table contains an ID column (PK) and a number of other columns.

I'm inserting the data from a csv into a temporary table #temp (same columns as the target table except for ID).

Then I try to merge them, but the merge is insanely slow (multiple hours for 10M rows).

```
-- Create temporal table #temp with almost all the columns in target_table
SELECT ColumnA,
        ColumnB,
        ColumnC,
        ColumnD,
        ColumnE,
        ColumnF,
        ColumnG,
        ColumnH
INTO #temp
FROM target_table
WHERE 1 = 2;

<HERE I DO A BULK INSERT INTO #temp WHICH ONLY TAKES A FEW SECONDS>

-- -- Merge into target_table
MERGE target_table AS TARGET
USING #temp AS SOURCE
ON (
            TARGET.ColumnA = SOURCE.ColumnA
        AND
            TARGET.ColumnB = SOURCE.ColumnB
        AND
            TARGET.ColumnC = SOURCE.ColumnC
        AND
            TARGET.ColumnE = SOURCE.ColumnE
    )
    
WHEN MATCHED
    AND (
            (TARGET.ColumnG IS NULL AND SOURCE.ColumnG IS NOT NULL OR TARGET.ColumnG <> SOURCE.ColumnG)
            OR
            (TARGET.ColumnH IS NULL AND SOURCE.ColumnH IS NOT NULL OR TARGET.ColumnH <> SOURCE.ColumnH)
        )
    THEN
    UPDATE SET TARGET.ColumnG = SOURCE.ColumnG, TARGET.ColumnH = SOURCE.ColumnH

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN
    INSERT (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD, ColumnE, ColumnF, ColumnG, ColumnH)
    VALUES (SOURCE.ColumnA, SOURCE.ColumnB, SOURCE.ColumnC, SOURCE.ColumnD, SOURCE.ColumnE, SOURCE.ColumnF,
            SOURCE.ColumnG, SOURCE.ColumnH);
```

After the bulk insert, the execution plan for the MERGE has some very expensive Sort's (41% of the total cost).

Any recommendations on how to speed up the merge?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add your table and index definitions to your question, and share a query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan, without which we cannot give any definite help. You probably want a clustered index on both tables `(ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnE)`

Comment: What is "millions" in relative terms? If you're updating/inserting so much that almost all of the data is being rewritten, one option to consider is to simply build a new table altogether (`SELECT` existing data, combine with new data, then bulk insert that), then use either `sp_rename` or a `truncate` and `alter table .. switch` to replace the original table entirely. Whether or not this is faster depends, but bulk inserting is hard to beat in terms of speed compared to more complex operations, and switching tables transactionally is hard to beat in terms of downtime.

Answer (score 1):

After inserting data to #temp table you can create a clustered index for the temp table:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX tbl_temp_index ON #temp (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnE);
```

This is increasing performance during the join process.
It would be good if you can create the same index for target_table too.

If you can update NULL values to default value on `ColumnG` and `ColumnH`, so you can replace this condition:

```
 (TARGET.ColumnG IS NULL AND SOURCE.ColumnG IS NOT NULL OR TARGET.ColumnG <> SOURCE.ColumnG)
 OR
 (TARGET.ColumnH IS NULL AND SOURCE.ColumnH IS NOT NULL OR TARGET.ColumnH <> SOURCE.ColumnH)
```

to:

```
    (TARGET.ColumnG <> SOURCE.ColumnG)
    OR
    (TARGET.ColumnH <> SOURCE.ColumnH)
```

I have tested this query on my computer. I created these tables and inserted 10 M sample records into the table. But I don't know what is the type of your `ColumnsA`, `ColumnsB` fields, I set integer type for these fields. Duration of executed this query (`create temp file, insert 10 M from CSV, and merge tables`) on my computer app. 20-25 seconds.